# Can't find Users created by seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a question about something weird that is happening to me.

I have a rails app, that I pre populated with some pre defined users, I run the command `rake db:seed` and it creates those users, I check with `rails c` and run `User.all` there they are. I run `User.find(1)` it returns a user. Ok, no problem.

But, when I start up the app, I have in one of my `user.rb`, the following code

`User.find(1) # I know that this user will have a fixed id throughout every environment`

But... it doesn't find, I get an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` Exception.

My goal, is after creating a new user in the database, to receive an welcome message from the `User.find(1)`. Can it be related to the fact that it's within a ActiveRecord callback, `after_commit`

EDIT:

My code is simple, after creating a new user, it recieves a message from a user `where(email: "theemail").first`

So my user.rb model has the following snippets:

```
after_commit :send_welcome_message

def send_welcome_message
  welcome_user = User.where(email: "xyz").first
  Conversation.send_welcome_message(self, welcome_user) 
end
```

I placed a debugger in the `send_welcome_message` checked the `User.all.size` and returned 1. I used the rails console, and the same query, returned 5.

Comment: Are you running **rake db:seed** in the same environment your are running the system?  I mean... one may to **RAILS_ENV=test rake db:seed** and then **RAILS_ENV=development rails s** and then there will be confusion.

Comment: I know it is a dumb question this one I did. But it happens. Shit happens, you know...

Comment: there's no such thing as dumb questions, I didn't specify the rails environment, but it was in development

Comment: Are you doing the `after_commit` method `on: :create` only? Can you include most or all of the `after_commit` method in your question?

Answer (score 1):

So your user with id 1 is not found. This doesn't mean you don't have access to the uses created by your seeds. The id numbers don't necessarily reset to 1 when you delete all users.

I.e. if you delete user 1, the next user you create will still have the id 2

The solution is probably to use some different method for looking up the user. I.e. you can set a special `name` for them in your seeds and then look them up later using that name.

Comment: hen we may suggest the OP to do a **rake db:drop** and **rake db:create** to recreate the database before seeding it. This would help to know if this is really the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you create three users, then delete them all, you're fourth user will have id value of 4. You can verify this by checking the ids of the Users when you call `User.all`

As mentioned above by @maxpleiner, it may be possible to look them up some other way, perhaps by a their name. The after commit block may prevent you from passing that user around the application since it calls itself in isolation. As mentioned in [Rails: Can you pass arguments to the after_create method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232820/rails-can-you-pass-arguments-to-the-after-create-method), you cannot pass the record into an after create. What you can do is add some custom code that gets placed immediately after you create the user which will handle your use case.